# Setting choices and forms at runtime for a Form Wizard?

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-forms, django-formwizard

I am trying to use Form Wizard but I can't figure out where to set the choices for the fields.

```
#views.py
class QuizWizard(SessionWizardView):
    def done(self, form_list, **kwargs):
        return render_to_response('done.html', {
            'form_data':[form.cleaned_data for form in form_list],
        })

#forms.py
class QuestionForm(forms.ModelForm):
    #selection = forms.ChoiceField()
    class Meta:
        model = Question
```

I see an empty form that looks like the admin panel for adding an object.
I would like to be able to pass a question to the form and have the question field filled out and not editable and preferable not submitted.

If I do

```
(r'^(?P<quiz_id>\d+)', QuizWizard.as_view(get_form_list)),
```

the function get_form_list has no length

```
(r'^(?P<quiz_id>\d+)', QuizWizard.as_view(get_form_list(quiz_id))),
```

Quiz_id is unknown.

so now I am trying to pass quiz_id to the view function and generate the list of question forms to be used in the form wizard

## urls.py

```
url(r'^(?P<quiz_id>\d+)', 'quiz.views.get_form_list'),
```

## views.py

```
class QuizWizard(SessionWizardView):
    def done(self, form_list, **kwargs):
        return render_to_response('done.html', {
            'form_data':[form.cleaned_data for form in form_list],
        })

def get_form_list(request, quiz_id):
    quiz = Quiz.objects.get(id=quiz_id)

    question_forms = []

    for question in quiz.questions.all():        
        choices = []
        for choice in question.choices.all():
            choices.append(choice)
        f = QuestionForm(instance=question)        
        question_forms.append(f)

    return QuizWizard.as_view(question_forms)(request)
```

I am getting the error message

```
issubclass() arg 1 must be a class
```

**Update based on Rohan's answer:**

```
def get_form_list(request, quiz_id):
    quiz = Quiz.objects.get(id=quiz_id)

    question_forms = []

    for question in quiz.questions.all():        
        choices = []
        for choice in question.choices.all():
            choices.append(choice)
        f = QuestionForm(instance=question)        
        question_forms.append(f)

    inst_dict = {}
    for idx, question in enumerate(question_forms):
        inst_dict[str(idx)] = question
    print inst_dict
    #inst_dict = { str(index(x)) : x for x in question_forms}

    QuestFormList = []
    for i in range(len(question_forms)):    
        QuestFormList.append(QuestionForm)

    QuizWizard.as_view(QuestFormList, instance_dict=inst_dict)(request)
```

With this code I am getting an error

```
'ModelFormOptions' object has no attribute 'many_to_many'
```

Here is my models.py

```
class Choice(models.Model):
    choice = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.choice

#create a multiple choice quiz to start
class Question(models.Model):
    question = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    answer = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    choices = models.ManyToManyField(Choice)
    module = models.CharField(max_length=64)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.question

class Quiz(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    questions = models.ManyToManyField(Question)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should call it using the class instead of object. So change your call to

```
QuizWizard.as_view(question_forms)(request)
```

Update:

The wizard view takes form class list as parameters not the form instance. You are creating form instances in `question_forms` and passing it to view.

If you want to pass instance for the form in each step, you can pass `instance_dict`.
Something like ...

```
inst_dict = { '0': question_forms[0], #step 0 instance
              '1': question_forms[1], #step 1 instance
            }
QuestFormList = [QuestionForm, QuestionForm ...]
QuizWizard.as_view([QuestFormList, instance_dict=inst_dict)(request)
```

Comment: In the view? If I do that I get the error "issubclass() arg 1 must be a class"

Comment: @Siecje, could you update question with what change you made.

Comment: I gave you the answer because I think now it is just the matter that my models are not compatible with this way of doing it. I have updated my post if you have any suggestions that would be great.